# GitHub repository as contributor

Tags: github

I created a repository and added a contributor, and this was our mutual work. In my GitHub account it appears as a repository and in his account is does not.

We want that his account will have this exact same repository as shown in my repos.

How can we do it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each repository is owned by a single individual or organization account. If you store your repository under your personal account, you would be the owner and your colleague can be made a collaborator. In this case, like you mention, the repository would be listed only in your account's repository list. To give equal "credit" to your collaborator, you could do one of the following:

1. [Pin the repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/pinning-items-to-your-profile): Your collaborator can pin any repository they contributed to to their profile page. While the repository would still appear under your name, it will be prominently visible on your collaborator's profile.
2. [Create an organization](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/creating-a-new-organization-from-scratch): You could create an organization where both of you are owners. The repository will then appear in neither of your individual profiles, and both your individual accounts can be publicly listed as members of the organization.